# How to print logs using log4j in selenium webdriver

Tags: log4j

Environment:
Java, Selenium webdriver, Maven, testNG, Log4J, Eclipse

1. XML

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
> <suite name="TestAll" parallel = "tests" thread-count = "2">
>
>  <test name="postivelogintest_IE">
>  <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
>
>  <classes>
>  <class name="com.dice.LoginTest">
>  <methods>
>  <include name="DataDrivenpositiveLoginTest"/>
>  </methods>
>  </class>
>  </classes>
>  </test>
>
>
>  <test name="postivelogintest_CH">
>  <parameter name="browser" value="ch"/>
>
>  <classes>
>  <class name="com.dice.LoginTest">
>  <methods>
>  <include name="DataDrivenpositiveLoginTest"/>
>  </methods>
>  </class>
>  </classes>
>  </test>
>
>
> </suite>
> ```

2. BaseTest.java

> ```
> package com.diceBase;
> import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
> import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
> import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
> import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
>
>
>
>
> public class BaseTest {
>  protected WebDriver driver;
>  protected Logger log;
>
>     @Parameters ({"browser"})
>  @BeforeMethod
>  protected void MethodSetup(String browser){
>  log.info("method set up"); // line 16
>  driver = BrowserFactory.getDriver(browser);
>  }
>
>  @AfterMethod
>  protected void TearDown(){
>  log.info("method tear down");
>
>
>  try {
>  Thread.sleep(5000);
>  driver.quit();
>  } catch (Exception e) {
>  }
>  }
> }
> ```

3. I added log4j.properties under src/main/resources.

   [image]
4. In the BaseTest.java, I added two lines after importing log4j.

   log.info("method set up");

   log.info("method tear down");

iMy goal is to be able to use log.info entire project. Before that, I would like to test it by only importing log4j logger in basetest class to see if it works. If it works then I can import log4j in entire project.

I get error if I keep both log messages. But, If I remove both log messages, script passes. How can I print the logs using log4j? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The log variable in your BaseTest.java has not assigned with object of logger class (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) . Since No object is assigned to the variable log, it throws NULL pointer exception. So please create object of logger class to varaiable log